# Flex-based Python data flow Terraform fails to run the template, yet the gcloud dataflow flex-template run command succeeds

Tags: python, dockerfile, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, continuous-deployment

I am attempting to deploy a Python based Dataflow Flex Template job using Terraform, written in Apache beam SDK. I have already built the Flex Template JSON file and stored it in my GCS bucket (**container_spec_gcs_path**). However, I am encountering an error when trying to run my Terraform code to deploy the Dataflow Flex Template job.

When I tried, I was successful in running the Flex template file via GCoud command as shown below:

```
gcloud --impersonate-service-account="sa-developer@prj-dfad-26-dfac-d-26.iam.gserviceaccount.com" dataflow flex-template run "dataflow-goat1" --template-file-gcs-location="gs://prj-dfad-26-dfac-d-26-dataflow-dev/template/dataflow-woproxy.json" --staging-location="gs://prj-dfad-26-dfac-d-26-dataflow-dev/staging/" --temp-location="gs://prj-dfad-26-dfac-d-26-dataflow-dev/temp/"  --subnetwork="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/prj-pp-gen-preprod-net-acc7/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/sb-vpc-pp-gen-preprod-us-central1" --disable-public-ips --region="us-central1" --service-account-email="sa-dfac-d@prj-dfad-26-dfac-d-26.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --worker-machine-type="n1-standard-4"
```

However, when I tried to use Terraform to accomplish the same thing, the template did not launch.  It throws the following error:

> Failed to start the VM, launcher-20230513094440393502020379059325, used for launching because of status code: FAILED_PRECONDITION, reason: Error:
> Message: Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 117738546194. Add instance projects/prj-dfad-26-dfac-d-26/zones/us-central1-a/instances/launcher-20230513094440393502020379059325 to the constraint to use external IP with it.
> HTTP Code: 412."

Public-ips have been disabled in my Terraform code. The code I was using for Terraform was:

```
resource "google_dataflow_flex_template_job" "dataflow-stream" {
provider                = google-beta
name                    = "dataflow-streaming"
container_spec_gcs_path = "gs://prj-dfad-26-dfac-d-26-dataflow-dev/template/dataflow-woproxy.json"
skip_wait_on_job_termination = true
region                = "us-central1"
project            = var.gcp_project_id
parameters = {
serviceAccount = var.service_account
subnetwork ="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/prj-pp-gen-preprod-net-acc7/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/sb-vpc-pp-gen-preprod-us-central1-2"
usePublicIps=false
tempLocation = "gs://prj-dfad-26-dfac-d-26-dataflow-dev/temp"
enableStreamingEngine=true
workerMachineType="n1-standard-4"
numWorkers=1
maxNumWorkers=5
}
}
```

I created the Flex template for the Python Beam Pipeline using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base

ARG WORKDIR=/dataflow/template
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}
COPY dataPipeline.py .
# # Do not include `apache-beam` in requirements.txt
RUN pip config set global.proxy http://proxy.com:23
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${WORKDIR}/dataPipeline.py"
# FROM python:3.8
RUN pip install apache-beam[gcp] 
RUN pip install google-cloud-bigquery==3.5.0
RUN pip install google-cloud==0.34.0 
RUN pip install google-cloud-storage==2.7.0
```

The options that I gave to the python beam library in my beam pipeline look something like this:

```
def run():

    o = PipelineOptions()
   
    standard_options = o.view_as(StandardOptions)
    standard_options.streaming = True
  

    logging.info("PipeLine is Starting Up")
    with beam.Pipeline(options=o) as p:
       
        alerts= (
            p
            | 'ReadfromPSub'>>beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=TOPIC_PATH1)
           
            | 'eventTable_notifTable_pushJSON'>>beam.ParDo(process_messages())
         
            |'pushtoCloudrun'>>beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=TOPIC_PATH2)
        )
    
    
    result = p.run()
  


    return result
```

I am aware that **wait_until_finish** is not supported by the Flex template. Does my run() method make any use of "wait_until_finish"? If so, how did the **gcloud dataflow flex-template run** command manage to run the template successfully?  Please help